# why it throws an exception,if its same type date time

Tags: c#

Am just trying to understand why this exception throws.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is what am trying to do

story.BroadcastOn is a date time value am getting from database (eg: 23/03/2012 1:56 Pm).

Am trying to convert the time from 12 to 24 hrs format,this is what i was trying to do

```
   DateTime testconverttime = story.BroadcastOn;`//this is where it throws exception
```

so i have to use the parse to get rid of this like below to solve my issue but it doesn't  make sense to me

```
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(story.BroadcastOn.ToString()))
            {
                 DateTime localTime = story.BroadcastOn.Value;//Thanks all for the great suggestion.
                converttime = localTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm ", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
```

already i converted my 12 hrs to 24hrs but trying to understand the exception,some one will give me an explanation please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime testconverttime = story.BroadcastOn.Value;
```

It's a nullable type (can have the null state also)

A nullable value type (DateTime is a value type), has the concept of the null value (no value). So if for example a column of datetime in database has nulls, then you can use `Nullable<DateTime>` or in short DateTime? to store the values which comes from that column.

About `DateTime.ToString()` and `String.ToDateTime()`: this is called `yo-yo` programming. You probably saw with *Debuger* that there is a representation of valid `DateTime`, which was giving by calling `ToString()`, but, in future, don't try to cast a type to another type via this `yo-yo technique`.

Comment: ,that's a great explanation to understand.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Try this, assuming the nullable type has a value:

```
DateTime testconverttime = story.BroadcastOn.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks ongle,in practical i was trying to do like story.BroadcastOn.ToString(dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm ", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),this suppose to convert rather than convert date time again to date time then convert string to do all this one line code

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime?` and `DateTime` are *not* the same type. `DateTime?` is the [nullable version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) of the `DateTime` type.

You should check whether it's null, and then either cast or retrieve the value of the nullable:

```
if (story.BroadcastOn.HasValue) {
    var broadcastOn = story.BroadcastOn.Value;
    // do stuff with broadcastOn
} else {
    // handle null BroadcastOn
}
```

or

```
if (story.BroadcastOn != null) {
    var broadcastOn = (DateTime) story.BroadcastOn;
    // do stuff with broadcastOn
} else {
    // handle null BroadcastOn
}
```

Using `.HasValue` or comparing with `null`, and using `.Value` and casting to the non-nullable type should be equivalent. You can also use the `??` operator.

Comment: am doing something similar in my code like   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(story.BroadcastOn.ToString()))
                {
                    DateTime localTime = DateTime.Parse(story.BroadcastOn.ToString());
                    converttime = localTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm ", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                }

Answer (score 2):

Try casting it as a `DateTime`, like so:

```
DateTime testconverttime = (DateTime)story.BroadcastOn
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.DateTime?` and `System.DateTime` are 2 different types. You need to use story.BroadcastOn.Value if you are sure if it is not null.

Comment: Thanks all for the great explanation,i never know that those are two different types and have null state also.Thanks a ton to enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime?` and `DateTime` are not the same type so you can not implicitly assign `DateTime?` to `DateTime`

You need to either explicitly cast it or assign the value via the `Value` property of `DateTime`.  However, if `BroadcastOn` is null, either method will throw an exception.

If you don't know `BroadcastOn` is not null then you best option to is use the null-coalescing operator:

```
DateTime dt = story.BroadcastOn ?? default(DateTime);
```